# Is it good to use Kubernetes from Rancher container management platform?

Tags: kubernetes, rancher

If it isn't good, why?

In another words, what's the different from original Kubernetes?

Comment: Can you provide any specifics about what your use case? Maybe the design of the app you plan on using it for and an idea of how you want to deploy it. Otherwise general recommendation questions tend to be closed as they are too broad to specifically answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMO using Kubernetes with Rancher is a great idea. I'm managing the rancher instances at my company and we'll move from Cattle to Kubernetes for several reasons:

**Kubernetes**
- Now widely used
- Open source
- Big companies supports its development
- RANCHER 2.0 WILL BE BUILT FOR KUBERNETES FIRST

I strongly recommand you to use Kubernetes if you plan to use Rancher.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I know k8s is very good. My question is that is it good to use k8s on Rancher or just install k8s itself is better? For private cloud, it's better to use Rancher as a big platform. For public cloud, such as AWS, whether it is good to use Rancher, then run k8s on it.

Comment: Hmm that's a good question. Rancher 2.0 will automatically create a K8s cluster for you. So I would recommand to use that. But as Rancher 2.0 isn't out yet...
I plan to use Rancher with K8s but I haven't it right now so be careful for the next statement : I would say create your cluster then add it to Rancher. With rancher 2.0 you will be able to upgrade your Rancher or simply add the cluster to the 2.0 version :).

Comment: Is it easy to upgrade Rancher from 1.x to 2.x? 1.x is based on docker and 2.x is based on kubernetes.